# interrupting REPL ILoop programmatically

Tags: scala

i have a wrapper for the scala REPL api (ILoop etc...) using the refactored 2.9.x classes.

this works well.

as this is a tool shipped to users, it is possible the user will type something like :

```
while(-1 < 1) {}
```

how can the user break from the currentlly executing code?

other posts talk about

```
<ctrl> + <c>
```

kind of working on some platforms under appropriate key bindings.

inspecting the scala REPL api and any available docs, it isnt obious how to actually implement this.

Comment: On Unix platforms ctrl c will simply send the SIGINT signal to your process. It depends on the way you handle this.

Comment: trapping the signal is not a problem. but once trapped, which place in the ILoop or other relevant class do i poke to interrupt a currentlly running command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out how the [Scala REPL does it](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/ILoopInit.scala) in the file `ILoopInit.scala`. There the following signal interrupt handler is installed,

```
  protected def installSigIntHandler() {
    // ....
    SignalManager("INT") = {
      if (intp == null || intp.lineManager == null)
        onExit()
      else if (intp.lineManager.running)
        intp.lineManager.cancel()
      // ...
    }
  }
```

Note that the field `intp: IMain` is defined in class `ILoop`, which is the self-type of `ILoopInit`.

To summarize: in your SIGINT handler you can interrupt the REPL with `intp.lineManager.cancel`.